# Redirect url just printing to screen - python

Tags: python, url, redirect, cgi-bin

I wrote a simple python script to redirect a url once an advertisement is clicked on.
The url associated with the advertisement is `http://server.example.com/redirect.py`.

The code for `redirect.py` is shown below:

```
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
print('Content-Type: text/html\n\n')
print('Location: http://www.finalurl.com')
```

However, instead of redirecting the request to `www.finalurl.com` when the advertisement is clicked on, the final url is simply displayed in the browser window.  All help is GREATLY appreciated.

Note that the `redirect.py` script is in the `/public_html/cgi-bin/` folder and the script has `711` permissions.  Also that the destination url will not always be the same url, it is based on a database query.  That code was simple omitted.

I also tried including: `print ("Status: 301 Moved")`

Comment: Please select the answer as accepted if you think this solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'\n\n' is end of http header marker, use instead:

```
print 'Status: 301 Moved Permanently'
print 'Location: http://www.finalurl.com'
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print # end of header
... # short html with the url
```